# compile static version of imagemagick convert util

Tags: macos, unix, ubuntu, compilation, imagemagick

looking to create static binaries for the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) convert utlity on two platforms: ubuntu and os x.

the only discussion that I can find that discusses how to do this is [from 2008](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11137), and is outdated.

I've tried downloading the .tar file from http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-7.0.0-0.tar.gz.

the discussion above suggests the following steps:

1. untarring, then building each delegate library as static (e.g.
   `./configure --disable-shared`)
2. globally building with `./configure --disable-shared --enable-delegate-build`
3. running `make`

which should build static versions of the main utilities.

I'm running into trouble building the delegate libraries as static, since the file structure of imagemagick has changed a lot in the past few years.

can somebody point me to the correct way to build a static version of the utility?

Comment: What kind of trouble exactly, is it not building at all, is there an error? Also which version of OSX are you using.

Comment: I'm in 10.9.5 and getting this error: `MagickCore/annotate.c:86:10: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found` I haven't done any building of delegate libraries as static, so that is probably the issue; I'm also not sure how to do that in this context.

Comment: Normally it's done pretty much the way you've described above, with maybe the exception of also using `--enable-static`. I just compiled the latest as a quick test and no issues encountered. The missing header file error you show is the FreeType 2 Library - (Which I installed via MacPorts ImageMagick sometime ago). Regardless if you use the MacPorts version you'll need to have those libraries installed/available. I found it was simple to install the MacPorts version, then everything is already installed for any custom versions like the one you're wanting to build.