# Is it possible to compile a static/portable version of ImageMagick for High Sierra/Mojave?

Tags: macos, compilation, imagemagick

This question was already asked, 4 years ago, so the High Sierra/Mojave part are new. Here is the link to the unanswered question:
[compile static version of imagemagick convert util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634129/compile-static-version-of-imagemagick-convert-util)

I am trying to compile portable version of IM that I can include with a script that could be used on other MacOS machines, without the need for developer tools or Mac Ports to first be installed on the machine. I see that ImageMagick.org provide static and portable builds for Windows, but only provide a precompiled binary for OS X/Darwin.

When I try to run the precompiled version on a Mac with a fresh install of Mojave I get the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/chrisnorman/Desktop/ImageMagick-7.0.8/bin/./magick
  Reason: image not found
```

When I run otool (which required that I install the command line developer tools) against the precompiled binary ot magick I get the following:

```
otool -L magick
magick:
    /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
```

which is a shorter list than I had gotten when I was trying to use a binary that I had compiled on another Mac and run on the fresh install of Mojave Mac.

I would just like some guidance on how to compile a version similar to the portable version of IM that they have precompiled for Windows on the ImageMagick downloads page. Something I can just throw on any Mac and run it without needing to worry about if a bunch of dynamic libraries are already installed on the machine.

Here is my current installation script for trying to build IM on a Mac that already has Xcode on it:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

IMBUILD=/tmp/imbuild/
mkdir -p $IMBUILD/bin

# get IM (Version 7 at the moment)
mkdir im_download && cd im_download
curl -O http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
for file in *.gz ; do tar zxf $file; done
rm *.tar.gz
cd ImageM*

# get delegates
# jpeg
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>> JPEG"
curl -O http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/jpegsrc.v9b.tar.gz
tar zxf jpeg*.gz && rm jpeg*.gz && mv jpeg* jpeg && cd jpeg
./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking
make
cd ..

# png
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>> PNG"
curl -O http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/libpng-1.6.31.tar.gz
tar zxf libpng*.gz && rm libpng*.gz && mv libpng* png && cd png
./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking
make
cd ..

# lcms
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>> LCMS"
curl -O http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/lcms2-2.8.tar.gz
tar zxf lcms2*.gz && rm lcms2*.gz && mv lcms2* lcms && cd lcms
./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking
make
cd ..

# tiff
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>> TIFF"
curl -O http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/tiff-4.0.8.tar.gz
tar zxf tiff*.gz && rm tiff*.gz && mv tiff* tiff && cd tiff
./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking
make
cd ..

#build imagemagick (YMMV)
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>> IMAGEMAGICK"
./configure --disable-shared \
    --disable-dependency-tracking \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-osx-universal-build \
    --enable-delegate-build \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-installed \
    --without-frozenpaths \
    --prefix=$IMBUILD \
    --with-openexr=no \
    --disable-docs \
    --with-lcms=yes \
    --without-x \
    --without-webp \
    --without-modules \
    --with-zero-configuration \
    --with-jpeg \
    --without-pango \
    --enable-hdri=no \
    --without-gvc \
    --with-raw

make install

ls $IMBUILD/bin
```

The configuration above is what I am going for, so what I need most are JPEG, TIFF and LCMS.

So any pointers or tips on what I need to add to this script to get a truly portable version of IM would be fantastic!

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but perhaps this thread might help.  See https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13145&hilit=static+Mac

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on this, but I read somewhere that the Apple linker always prefers dynamic libraries over static ones, i.e. it chooses libraries ending in `.dylib` in preference to libraries ending in `.a`.

So, I copied your shell script and edited it to build ImageMagick with very few options enabled in order to reduce the configure/build time. Then I dinked around with the options.

I have not done any exhaustive testing and don't have a spare clean Mac lying around without my beloved ImageMagick on it. However, I built **ImageMagick** and checked the dependencies with:

```
otool -L ./magick

./magick:
    /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 54.0.0, current version 54.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/fftw/lib/libfftw3.3.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.8.0)
    /usr/local/opt/fontconfig/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib (compatibility version 14.0.0, current version 14.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 24.0.0, current version 24.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
```

I then discovered that if I temporarily rename the `libpng` dynamic library and rebuild (after using `make distclean`), then the dependency disappears.

I assume (guess/hope) therefore that if you deleted (or maybe preferably renamed) the dynamic libraries in all your delegates, it would link statically and you might get something redstributable.

As an example, here's how I forced `libjpeg` to link statically. As mine is installed via **homebrew**, I find the dynamic library like this:

```
brew ls --verbose jpeg | grep dylib
```

And that tells me it is here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9c/lib/libjpeg.dylib
```

So, I go there and hide that from the linker:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9c/lib
mv libjpeg.dylib HIDDENlibjpeg.dylibHIDDEN
```

---

Here's the script I was using:

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# macBuildPortableMagick
# Mark Setchell
#
# Build PORTABLE ImageMagick from source and install under my user without 
# clashing with any system derived packages.
################################################################################
INSTALLDIR=$HOME/ImageMagick
BUILDDIR=$HOME/ImageMagick/ImageMagick

# Create the installation directory
mkdir -p "$INSTALLDIR"

# Go to the distribution, clean, build and install
cd "$BUILDDIR"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then 
   >&2 echo ERROR: Unable to change directory to $BUILDDIR
   exit 1
fi

make distclean

./configure \
   CC=clang \
   CFLAGS="-O3" \
   CXX=clang++ \
   CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -O3 -march=native"  \
   --disable-dependency-tracking \
   --without-x \
   --without-magick-plus-plus \
   --disable-shared \
   --enable-static \
   --with-quantum-depth=16 \
   --enable-hdri=no \
   --prefix="$INSTALLDIR" \
   --disable-docs \
   --disable-osx-universal-binary \
   --disable-silent-rules \
   --enable-zero-configuration \
   --with-jpeg \
   --with-heic=no \
   --with-lcms=no \
   --with-openexr=no \
   --with-openjp2=no \
   --with-tiff=no \
   --with-xml=no \
   --with-webp=no
   
# I prefer to check things before copying and pasting the next bit
exit
make -j 8 && make install
```

---

If anyone knows more about this and can add some insights - please let me know via comments or by editing and adding a new paragraph at the end of the answer.

---

Added in response to comments from @emendelson If you want to use JPEGXL, you need to carry out the following steps ***before*** the answer above:

```
brew install pkg-config
brew install jpeg-xl

# This should work on Intel and Apple Silicon Macs
./configure PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(brew --prefix)/lib/pkgconfig | grep "JPEG XL"
JPEG XL           --with-jxl=yes            yes
```

And you are looking for `yes` in the rightmost column to be sure JPEG-XL support is built in. Then just build and install with:

```
make -j && make install
```

Comment: Your script is a marvel, but with current code in macOS, I get this error `coders/jxl.c:64:10: fatal error: 'jxl/decode.h' file not found`. Is there any hope that you have a solution? Thank you.

Comment: @emendelson It looks like you are trying to use JPEGXL, so I guess you'd need to install that with **homebrew** first. I am nowhere near a Mac for days, so you'll need to try for yourself, see https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jpeg-xl#default

Comment: @emendelson Note the `docker alpine` version of **ImageMagick** is very simple to use on macOS, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032739/2836621

Comment: Thank you! I already figured out that I had jpeg-xl installed with homebrew, and that the library that the make command can't find is located at `opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg-xl/0.8.2_1/include/jxl`. Now I suppose I have to figure out how to include that in the script. - And thank you for pointing me to `docker alpine`. My goal is to create a portable app that can convert to `wpg` format (as ImageMagick can do from the command line), and I don't think that's practical with `docker alpine` but I could be wrong.

Comment: @emendelson You may find that it helps if you install `pkgconfig/pkg-config` with **homebrew** first as **ImageMagick** can more readily find packages with that. Then you want to find JPEG-XL's `pkgconfig` file with `find /opt -name "*jpeg*xl*.pc` and make sure its containing directory is included in your PKGCONFIGPATH variable.

Comment: Some related, but not identical, notes about `pkgconfig` are here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609555/2836621

Comment: There's no reason why you should spend your time helping me with my incompetence, but here's where I stand. The `find` command that you offered (it needed a closing double-quote) didn't find anything, but I found `libxl.pc` in this path: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg-xl/0.8.2_1/lib/pkgconfig/` and so I tried adding this near the top of your script: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg-xl/0.8.2_1/lib/pkgconfig/`. Because I don't know what I'm doing, I got the same error as before. I'll keep trying to get this right. And thank you again! (I already had brew `pkg-config`)

Comment: @emendelson I'll try and take a look when I get home on Sunday.

Comment: You are generous beyond the call of ANY duty. And I certainly won't complain if you decide not to spend any more time on this.

Comment: @emendelson I did some experiments and added a section to the bottom of my answer. HTH.

Comment: Thank you again for this effort. I followed your procedure exactly, and got the "yes" in the ./configure output, but the build failed with the same error as before. I'm about to try it on another machine to see if something is wrong with this one.

Comment: I went to another ARM machine with Sonoma, installed brew for the first time, installed pkg-config and jpeg-xl via brew, and ran your configure command - but got the same error about jxl/decode.h - Again, please don't spend a lot of time on this!

Comment: I made some progress. I got rid of the jxl\decode.h file-not-found error by installing jxl from source, according to this page: https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl/blob/main/BUILDING.md (I used brew install cmake in order to build) - but I then got a linker error saying that library jpeg wasn't found. I reinstalled jpeg from brew, and tried installing jpeg from source using this page: https://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/libjpeg/ (after creating the folder structure). Same error. I tried various ways of pointing toward the jpeg library with CFLAGS and LFLAGS, but I don't know how to get it right

Comment: Also tried install jpeg as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496349/compile-imagemagick-from-source-with-png-support-on-osx - but again got the error that the jpeg library was not found.

Comment: Mmm, if you run `brew info jpeg` it tells you it is *"keg only"* which means it is not linked so `./configure` will not find it without setting some extra flags, so maybe try that.

Comment: Well, you are a hero. That make it possible to build. Thank you again! - I still can't figure out how to create a portable build, as `otool -L` lists ten libraries in `/opt/homebrew/opt` and I can't find any flags in ./configure that change that. `enable-static=yes enable-shared=no enable-zeroconfiguration` have no effect. Possibly there's no solution? Meanwhile, again thank you for your patience and persistence and expertise!

Comment: I later remembered your technique of temporarily renaming libraries - and tried that, but either the build failed or `magick` failed to do a conversion afterwards. a fully portable imagemagick may be impossible...

Comment: I can't figure out how to make a portable executable, but I've done the next best thing: I built according to your instructions (slightly simplified) and moved the executable into a macOS app (I used an existing app and replaced the executable with `magick` and edited the `info.plist`.) I then used `dylibbundler` (from brew) to copy all the dependencies into the app. The app is now portable (or should be - I'm about to test it on another machine), and you can run the executable inside it from the terminal. I'll post a link to the app (ARM only so far) if anyone wants it. Thank you yet again!

Comment: And of course it is possible to create a symlink in the path (maybe `/usr/local/bin`) that links to the `magick` instance in the self-contained app, making it easy to run ImageMagick from the terminal.

Comment: And further, `/usr/local/bin` may not exist, so another location may be needed.

Comment: You've done quite a lot of good work here. It may be an idea to ask a new question that is more specific to what you are actually doing and then answer it yourself with all your insights and thoughts so other folks can see it and use it without needing to scrabble around in the comments of a 4-year old question. You can always link back to this question and link forwards to the new one. To make a link, click the `Share` button at the end of a question or answer then click `Copy link`

Comment: That was basically what I had in mind to do next, but I wasn't familiar enough with stackoverflow to know what I could do without getting a dozen people telling me that I shouldn't have done it the way I did it. I'll follow your insructions. Before I go forward, I want to figure out where a user can create a symlink to the executable that will NOT be in `/usr/local/bin` because that path may not exist. I can't figure out which location to suggest that is guaranteed (1) to be in the `PATH` and (2) to exist on everyone's system.

Comment: I am not sure there is such a place, and if there is, it is likely protected by SIP *"System Integrity Protection"*. You could try asking that as a question on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: That seems to be correct. What I'm thinking of doing is writing a shell script or AppleScript that offers to createf `/usr/local/bin` if it does not exist (`sudo mkdir -p -m 775 /usr/local/bin`) and add it to the path. I haven't tested the method for adding it to the path, but this is reported to work: `sudo launchctl config user path /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: A minor snag: I can't build this on intel. I've added `brew install webp openexr little-cms2` which seem to be needed, and I've replaced the flags paths with `/usr/local/opt`, and the executable builds, but when I try to convert a png file, I get the error `DelegateLibrarySupportNotBuiltIn <filename> (XML) @ error /profile.c/ValidateXMPProfile/1943.` I'll scratch my head over this one, but I do have libpng installed via brew. (This is on Monterey, the most recent macOS my Intel machine supports.)

Comment: If you use `$(brew --prefix)` everywhere, it should give you `/usr/local` on Intel and `/opt/homebrew` on Apple Silicon.

Comment: Yes, I think I have this right. On Intel my configure string looks like this: `CC=clang \
   CFLAGS="-O3" \
   CXX=clang++ \
   CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -O3 -march=native"  \
   LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib"  \
   CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/jpeg/include" \
   --disable-dependency-tracking \
   --without-x \
   --without-magick-plus-plus \
   --disable-shared \
   --enable-static`  But the resulting build won't open png files. And when I run `tool -L` it lists `/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib`. So I'm baffled.

Comment: Have now built on Monterey and Ventura and Sonoma on ARM. Monterey required changing the jxl code by removing an `ld` instruction (exclude-libs=all) which wasn't supported on ARM Monterey. But the result seems to work. - I haven't succeeded on making a working build on Intel Monterey, but will try again when I have access to a newer Intel machine. I'll write up all the details after I've managed to build an Intel version. Thank you again!

Comment: One last report before I post a new question and answer. Have now succeeded in building on Intel (Monterey and later). So, thanks to your help, this problem is solved. Thank you again!

Comment: As suggested, I've posted an expanded solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77767021/how-to-build-a-portable-version-of-imagemagick-for-macos-monterey-ventura-sonoma/77767022#77767022 - and all the serious work was done by Mark Setchell.