# ImageMagick cannot get file from HTTPS from inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagick 7 in a Docker container. However it doesn't install any delegates, though I added `libpng-dev`. When I try to get an image inside the container from https with this command:

```
magick https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/moon_mosaic.png ./test.png
```

I get this message:

```
magick: no decode delegate for this image format `DAT' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/738.
```

This doesn't make sense, since it is a `PNG` image and not a `DAT` file.

Here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

ARG IM_VERSION="7.1.0-37"
ARG IM_BUILD_FLAGS="--enable-shared --disable-static --without-modules --enable-delegate-build --disable-docs --with-heic=yes"

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential curl libpng-dev && \
    wget https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/archive/refs/tags/${IM_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf ${IM_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    rm ${IM_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoremove
    
WORKDIR /app/ImageMagick-${IM_VERSION}
RUN sh ./configure ${IM_BUILD_FLAGS} && make -j && make install && ldconfig /usr/local/lib/
```

Here the output from the configure part of building ImageMagick:

```
configure:
==============================================================================
ImageMagick 7.1.0-37 is configured as follows. Please verify that this
configuration matches your expectations.
Host system type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Build system type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
                  Option                        Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shared libraries  --enable-shared=yes       yes
Static libraries  --enable-static=no        no
Build utilities   --with-utilities=yes      yes
Module support    --with-modules=no     no
GNU ld            --with-gnu-ld=yes     yes
Quantum depth     --with-quantum-depth=16   16
High Dynamic Range Imagery
                  --enable-hdri=yes     yes
Install documentation:              no
Memory allocation library:
  JEMalloc          --with-jemalloc=no      no
  TCMalloc          --with-tcmalloc=no      no
  UMem              --with-umem=no      no
Delegate library configuration:
  BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yes        no
  Autotrace         --with-autotrace=no     no
  DJVU              --with-djvu=yes     no
  DPS               --with-dps=yes      no
  FFTW              --with-fftw=no      no
  FLIF              --with-flif=no      no
  FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yes      no
  FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yes   no
  FreeType          --with-freetype=yes     no
  Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=no     no
  Graphviz          --with-gvc=yes      no
  HEIC              --with-heic=yes     no
  JBIG              --with-jbig=yes     no
  JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes     no
  JPEG XL           --with-jxl=no       no
  LCMS              --with-lcms=yes     no
  LQR               --with-lqr=yes      no
  LTDL              --with-ltdl=no      no
  LZMA              --with-lzma=yes     no
  Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yes yes
  OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes      no
  OpenJP2           --with-openjp2=yes      no
  PANGO             --with-pango=yes        no
  PERL              --with-perl=no      no
  PNG               --with-png=yes      no
  RAQM              --with-raqm=yes     no
  RAW               --with-raw=yes      no
  RSVG              --with-rsvg=no      no
  TIFF              --with-tiff=yes     no
  WEBP              --with-webp=yes     no
  WMF               --with-wmf=no       no
  X11               --with-x=           no
  XML               --with-xml=yes      no
  ZIP               --with-zip=yes      no
  ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes     no
  ZSTD              --with-zstd=yes     no
Delegate program configuration:
  GhostPCL          None            pcl6 (unknown)
  GhostXPS          None            gxps (unknown)
  Ghostscript       None            gs (unknown)
Font configuration:
  Apple fonts       --with-apple-font-dir=default   
  Dejavu fonts      --with-dejavu-font-dir=default  none
  Ghostscript fonts --with-gs-font-dir=default      none
  URW-base35 fonts  --with-urw-base35-font-dir=default  none
  Windows fonts     --with-windows-font-dir=default none
X11 configuration:
  X_CFLAGS        = 
  X_PRE_LIBS      = 
  X_LIBS          = 
  X_EXTRA_LIBS    = 
Options used to compile and link:
  PREFIX          = /usr/local
  EXEC-PREFIX     = /usr/local
  VERSION         = 7.1.0-37
  CC              = gcc
  CFLAGS          = -fopenmp -Wall -g -O2 -mtune=ivybridge -fexceptions -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
  CPPFLAGS        =  -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
  PCFLAGS         = 
  DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
  LDFLAGS         = 
  LIBS            =                                         -lm    -lpthread 
  CXX             = g++
  CXXFLAGS        =  -pthread
  FEATURES        = DPC HDRI Cipher OpenMP
  DELEGATES       = 
==============================================================================
```

All delegates seem to be not active.

EDIT: I checked the output again. It seems like it doesn't find libpng

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
checking for libpng >= 1.0.0... no
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I checked the installed version and it is 1.6.37-3

When I use ImageMagick outside of the Docker container it works without problems. I'm not sure what the problem is and why it doesn't configure the delegates. Sadly I can't install ImageMagick 7 with `apt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `pkg-config`, and possibly also `autoconf`, to your prerequisite package list. **ImageMagick** is considerably better at finding and configuring stuff with those helpers, especially the PNG delegate:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y autoconf pkg-config ...
```

---

Actually, the **Alpine** docker image is *brilliant* for **ImageMagick**. It is very current, very small, and includes *loads* of delegates:

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)":/work -w /work alpine:latest

/work # apk add --no-cache imagemagick
...
... output, output, output
... and then around 4 seconds later
...

/work # magick identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-50 beta Q16-HDRI x86_64 20489 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jpeg jxl lcms ltdl lzma png ps rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (11.2)
```

Comment: Be sure to check your policy.xml file. There is a item for permissions of HTTPS.

Comment: @fmw42 Good thinking! Thank you. Another option is maybe to `curl/wget` the file from https: to local disk first - I see OP installed `curl` package.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. I tried your suggested fix for the old image and it worked. Also the alpine version works. Now I have to decide which one I'm going to use ;) I have a Golang app which reads images from https with a Golang ImageMagick library and ImageMagick is internally getting those images with curl and puts it in a temp file. (If you haven't installed it, there will be a error message).

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project!