# how to install imagemagick 7 on ubuntu image

Tags: imagemagick

I want to install imagemagick v7.
I need the command(s) to add in my Dockerfile.

This command installs v6.9 and this version did not have `magick` command

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends imagemagick
```

can anyone helps  me to find how to install imagemagick v7 to have magick command? Thank you very much

Comment: I hope this helps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042436/how-to-install-delegate-libraries-for-image-magick-7-0-7

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but the Alpine docker image is very good for **ImageMagick**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032739/2836621

Comment: There are many, many image file formats (180+) and many, many features such as HDR, FFT, Pango, liquid-rescaling so you would end up installing tens or hundreds of dependencies and megabytes unless you were more specific about what you need and what you are trying to do. Installing from source is likely to be your only option if you want v7 on debian or ubuntu. It's not actually that difficult, you just have to have some specific goal and feature-set in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y autoconf pkg-config

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential curl libpng-dev && \
    wget https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/archive/refs/tags/7.1.0-31.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf 7.1.0-31.tar.gz && \
    rm 7.1.0-31.tar.gz && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoremove

RUN sh ./ImageMagick-7.1.0-31/configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-bzlib=yes --with-fontconfig=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-gvc=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-jp2=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes --with-xml=yes --with-gs-font-dir=yes && \
    make -j && make install && ldconfig /usr/local/lib/
```

you can change the version of you want