# The system library `MagickWand` required by crate `magick_rust` was not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, rust, imagemagick

I'm trying to deploy Rust with Image magic support via docker, can't seem to get image magic to work.

Here is the docker

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Change package repository to a different mirror
RUN sed -i 's/archive.ubuntu.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# Update
RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing
RUN apt install -y wget
RUN apt-get -y install curl

# For video compression
RUN apt install -y ffmpeg
# For querying files
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# PNG ,JPG ,Tiff & WebP support
# Consider adding more support with testing https://gist.github.com/hurricup/e14ae5bc47705fca6b1680e7a1fb6580
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libjpeg-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libpng-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libtiff-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libwebp-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libheif-dev

# Install image magic
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev openssl pkg-config libmagickwand-dev
RUN apt-get -y install wget && apt-get install -y ruby-full && ruby -v
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" UBUNTU_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install imagemagick -y

# Install ImageMagick
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" UBUNTU_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install imagemagick -y

# Install Rust
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"
RUN rustup default stable

# Move app and build app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Compile rust app
RUN cargo build --release

# Remove the source so no one can steal it.
RUN rm -r -d src
RUN rm -r -d k8s

ENV DOCKER isdocker
ENV PORT 8080

# Start the app.
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/app/poem_test"]
```

On RUN cargo build --release

I get

```
.7 Caused by:
677.7   process didn't exit successfully: `/app/target/release/build/magick_rust-a30fa2e709188d5a/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
677.7   --- stdout
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=IMAGE_MAGICK_LIB_DIRS
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=IMAGE_MAGICK_DIR
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=MAGICKWAND_NO_PKG_CONFIG
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=MAGICKWAND_STATIC
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=MAGICKWAND_DYNAMIC
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
677.7   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
677.7 
677.7   --- stderr
677.7   thread 'main' panicked at /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/magick_rust-0.19.1/build.rs:249:10:
677.7   called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: 
677.7   pkg-config exited with status code 1
677.7   > PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --libs --cflags MagickWand MagickWand >= 7.0
677.7 
677.7   The system library `MagickWand` required by crate `magick_rust` was not found.
677.7   The file `MagickWand.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
677.7   The PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is not set.
677.7 
677.7   HINT: if you have installed the library, try setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory containing `MagickWand.pc`.
677.7 
677.7   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
677.7 warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
------
Dockerfile:48
--------------------
  46 |     
  47 |     # Compile rust app
  48 | >>> RUN cargo build --release
```

Comment: did you do what it says to do?

Comment: @drewtato yes the issue with entirly unrelated. Was because the new Rust version doesn't support Debian Bullseye. This error was completely useless.

Comment: You are installing imagemagic 6; in the past i have been using other docker images which already have imagemagic 7 installed, the installation process is not easy

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74951619/how-to-install-imagemagick-7-on-ubuntu-image

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Debian and upgrading the version helped. Here is the script that works on production.

```
####################################################################################################
## Builder
####################################################################################################
FROM rust:latest AS builder

RUN apt update && apt upgrade

RUN update-ca-certificates

# RUN wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
# RUN dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

# Create appuser
ENV USER=myip
ENV UID=10001

RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    "${USER}"


WORKDIR /app

# Install ImageMagick
RUN apt-get -y install clang build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev openssl pkg-config
RUN apt-get -y install wget && apt-get install -y ruby-full && ruby -v
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" UBUNTU_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install -y

# Install from scratch
ENV MAGICK_VERSION 7.1
RUN curl https://imagemagick.org/archive/ImageMagick.tar.gz | tar xz \
    && cd ImageMagick-${MAGICK_VERSION}* \
    && ./configure --with-magick-plus-plus=no --with-perl=no \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -r ImageMagick-${MAGICK_VERSION}*
RUN ldconfig /usr/lib64

RUN cd /app

# Cache Rust dependencies
# Copy your manifests
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.lock ./
# Create a dummy main.rs if necessary
RUN mkdir src/ && echo "fn main() {println!(\"If you see this in app, the build broke\")}" > src/main.rs
# Build only the dependencies to cache them
RUN cargo build --release
# Remove the dummy main.rs and copy the actual source code
RUN rm -f target/release/deps/protobrain-api* #
RUN rm -rf src/

# Copy the main project back and build
COPY ./src /app/src

# Needed to break the cargo cache
RUN touch ./src/main.rs 

# Build for release
RUN cargo build --release

####################################################################################################
## Final image
####################################################################################################
FROM debian:bookworm

RUN apt update && apt upgrade

RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libjpeg-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libpng-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libtiff-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libwebp-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing libheif-dev

RUN apt-get -y install openssl libc6 libgomp1 libnss3 libjbig0 libx11-6 liblcms2-2 liblqr-1-0 libdjvulibre21 libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libgif-dev libwebp-dev libheif-dev librsvg2-dev libdjvulibre-dev libwmf-dev libgs-dev liblcms2-dev libfreetype6-dev libopenexr-dev libfftw3-dev

RUN find / -name 'libjbig.so.0' 2>/dev/null

# Copy image magic from builder
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/lib/

RUN ldconfig

# Import from builder.
COPY --from=builder /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=builder /etc/group /etc/group

WORKDIR /app

# Copy our build
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/api ./
COPY ./GeoIP2-City.mmdb /app/GeoIP2-City.mmdb

# Use an unprivileged user.
USER myip:myip

ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/app/api"]
```

Comment: No idea why someone has downvoted you but it looks pretty reasonable. You might want `make -j` to build in parallel which should be faster - unless on a Raspberry Pi zero.

Answer (score -1):

You are installing ImageMagick 6, but the crate requires you to install ImageMagick 7.

You can either build ImageMagick 7 from source or build upon other docker images already packaging ImageMagic 7:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/dpokidov/imagemagick
- [how to install imagemagick 7 on ubuntu image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74951619/how-to-install-imagemagick-7-on-ubuntu-image)
- https://github.com/dooman87/imagemagick-docker/blob/main/Dockerfile.ubuntu