# How to make a portable macOS build of ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

How can I build a portable version of ImageMagick on macOS? The standard way to get ImageMagick on macOS is to use `brew`, but the `brew` version can't be used in apps and utilities that run on machines that don't have `brew` installed.

For older versions of macOS (pre-Mojave) Mark Setchell solved this problem here, but his solution doesn't work on recent macOS versions.

[Is it possible to compile a static/portable version of ImageMagick for High Sierra/Mojave?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56765527/3497341)

Any answers will be useful. (I'll try to provide one myself, but I know it can be improved.)

Answer (score 2):

An answer seems to be this; it's probably incompetent, but it seems to work, and everything in it that shows any intelligence is the work of Mark Setchell.

**How to build portable ImageMagick for macOS:**

You will need `brew`, but do NOT install `imagemagick` from brew, because the portable version will not build if the brew version is present.

Install these packages from brew (possibly not all of them are needed, but it can't hurt to install them)

`brew install cmake jpeg dylibbundler webp openexr little-cms2 pkg-config glib fontconfig ghostscript freetype gettext libzip libraqm libheif jbigkit pango libraw libwmf djvulibre pango librsvg`

Install `liblqr`:

Download the code from https://github.com/carlobaldassi/liblqr
cd into the liblqr directory

```
./configure && make 
sudo /usr/bin/install -c lqr/.libs/liblqr-1.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/liblqr-1.0.dylib
```

Install `jxl`:

Start in any convenient directory

`git clone https://github.com/libjxl/libjxl.git --recursive --shallow-submodules`

On Intel and on ARM Monterey:
edit `libjxl/lib/jxl_cms.cmake` and `libjxl/lib/jxl.cmake` by commenting out (or deleting) the line:

`set(LINKER_EXCLUDE_LIBS_FLAG "-Wl,--exclude-libs=ALL")`

```
cd libjxl
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF ..
cmake --build . -- -j$(nproc)
sudo cmake --install .
```

Now CD into your user directory or other convenient directory.

```
git clone https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.git ImageMagick-7.1.1
cd ImageMagick-7.1.1
```

On Apple Silicon:

```
make distclean
./configure \
   CC=clang \
   CFLAGS="-O3" \
   CXX=clang++ \
   CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -O3 -march=native"  \
   LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg/lib"  \
   CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg/include" \
   --disable-dependency-tracking \
   --without-x \
   --without-magick-plus-plus \
   --disable-shared \
   --enable-static
# check things before copying and pasting the next bit
exit
make -j 8
```

On intel:

```
make distclean
./configure \
   CC=clang \
   CFLAGS="-O3" \
   CXX=clang++ \
   CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -O3 -march=native"  \
   LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib"  \
   CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/jpeg/include" \
   --disable-dependency-tracking \
   --without-x \
   --without-magick-plus-plus \
   --disable-shared \
   --enable-static
# check things before copying and pasting the next bit
exit
make -j 8
```

The executable `magick` will be in the `utilities` folder; if you run it, you'll probably get an error message. To avoid this, find a simple app on your sysytem; make a copy of it; rename the copy `Magick.app`. Replace the the executable in `Contents/MacOS` with `magick`. Edit the `info.plist` file to use `magick` instead of the original executable. Remove any other irrelevant contents.

*The app that you create will do nothing when you click on it! It exists only as a container for the executable and its required libraries!*

cd to the directory with the `Magick.app` that you created.

Before you run the `dylibbundler` command below, keep in mind that you may be prompted for the location of a libjxl library; if that happens, enter: `/usr/local/lib`

On Apple Silicon:

`dylibbundler -od -of -b -x ./Magick.app/Contents/MacOS/magick -d ./Magick.app/Contents/libs-arm/ -p @executable_path/../libs-arm/`

Under Ventura or later, you may want to add the `-ns` parameter to avoid an error message

On Intel:

`dylibbundler -od -of -b -x ./Magick.app/Contents/MacOS/magick -d ./Magick.app/Contents/libs-intel/ -p @executable_path/../libs-intel/`

Now use the `magick` executable in the app from the command line. You can create a symlink to it in `/usr/local/bin` so that you can use `magick` without entering a path.

If you want to build a universal app, build on both Intel and Apple Silicon and use `lipo` to combine the `magick` executables. Make sure to include both the `libs-arm` and `libs-intel` folders in the universal app.

EDIT: And I've posted a DMG with a notarized universal version of the app and an installer script that moves it into the Applications folder and creates a symlink in `/usr/local/lib`:

https://mendelson.org/PortableImageMagickInstaller.dmg

Comment: I forgot to add: please do not waste your valuable time posting a comment saying "use brew." As it says above, the point is to make something portable that can be used in utilties or applications where the user doesn't have brew and can't be asked to install it.